# NullPointerException on Tablets only when using Fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I get `NullPointerException` when using my app on Tablets while it works fine on Emulater(Tablet + phone) and phones.

The problem seems to be when communicating with other Fragment.

My tablet is 1280x800, 7"

**I have five XML files:**

> activity_main.xml  
>   activity_main.xml(land)  
>   activity_main.xml(sw600dp)  
>   iteminfo_fragment.xml  
>   listview_fragment.xml

**Activity_Main.java**

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListViewFragment.OnitemClickedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(findViewById(R.id.layout_container) != null){

            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                return;
            }

            ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_container,listViewFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
            ItemInfo_Fragment itemInfo_fragment = (ItemInfo_Fragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.ListView_ItemFragmentID);

        if(itemInfo_fragment != null) {
            itemInfo_fragment.updateInfo(position);
        } else {
            ItemInfo_Fragment itemInfo_fragment1 = new ItemInfo_Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            itemInfo_fragment1.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_container, itemInfo_fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListViewFragment.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Sarbast on 30/06/2016.
 */
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment {


    OnitemClickedListener mCallBack;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heros);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Highlight the item when using two-pane layout
        Fragment fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.ListView_ItemFragmentID);
        ListView v = getListView();

        if (fragmentManager != null && v != null){
            v.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try{
            mCallBack = (OnitemClickedListener) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(e.toString() + "Must implement OnItemClickedInstance");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        mCallBack.onItemClick(position);
    }

    public interface OnitemClickedListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position);
    }
}
```

**itemInfo_Fragment.java**

```
public class ItemInfo_Fragment extends Fragment {

    TextView mTextView;
    String[] mStrings;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.iteminfo_fragment, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.showInfo_ID);
        mStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heros_info);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            int index = args.getInt("position");
            mTextView.setText(mStrings[index]);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void updateInfo(int position){
        mTextView.setText(mStrings[position]);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.sarbast.android.listfragmenttest, PID: 26930
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.sarbast.android.listfragmenttest.ListViewFragment$OnitemClickedListener.onItemClick(int)'
>   on a null object reference   at
>   com.******.android.listfragmenttest.ListViewFragment.onListItemClick(ListViewFragment.java:63)
>   at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)   at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:340)   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1532)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3700) 
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5686)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Answer (score 0):

your callback interface is never initialized,

so calling the method

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      mCallBack.onItemClick(position);
}
```

is throwing a null pointer Exception

you need to check the null before triggering the callback

```
if(mCallBack!=null){
     mCallBack.onItemClick(position);
}
```

or define a setter method that allows you to initialize the interface properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i know the exact problem but still have no idea where and how i should initialize `mCallBack` because developers.android doesn't mention initializing it or `onAttach` is where we initialize it. and why does it work on Phones without initializing it?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully i found the answer, since i use API lower than 23 which is 22 on my Tablet and doesn't use support library then `onAttach(Context context)` is never gets called so i had to use `onAttach(Activity activity)`